# Suppose that $f$ is a function such that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x) = 4$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}f(x) = \infty$

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Suppose that $f$ is a function such that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x) = 4$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}f(x) = \infty$. Which of thefollowing might be true?

(a) $f$ is continuous at each $a\in\mathbb{R}$

(b) $\lim_{x\rightarrow 7^-} f(x) = -\infty$

(c) $f(0) = 4$

(d) $f(x) < 0$ for at least $13$ values of $x$

(e) For all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ we have that $f(x+4) = f(x)$

(f) None of the above.

The answers are a, b, c, and d, according to the practice problems answer key, but I do not understand why. Could someone please explain?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here]For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): show your efforts (even if unsuccessful) to decide the answer to each of a,b,...,e. Moreover, imo you didn't read the key corresponding to that exercise, but another one; please double-check.

Comment: "I don't understand why" is not a good reason. You need to elaborate on what you have tried so that we can help you.

Comment: All you know is roughly what the function does for very large positive $x$, and for very large negative $x$. For any $x$ in between, you have basically free reign. Do you want $f(0) = 4$? No problem: just take any function with those limits and change the value to $4$ (we don't need it to be continuous). Want it to be less than $0$ at thirteen points? Simple: pick thirteen points, and change the values of those $13$ points to $-1$. Want an asymptote at $-7$? Just change the function to $1/(x + 7)$ for $-8 < x < -7$. You don't need explicit formulas to know there examples of such functions.

Answer (score 1):

I think a key part of the question you might be missing is this: the question isn't asking which of those options MUST be true, it's only asking which of them COULD be true. It's a lot easier to think of some examples where each of these are individually true, I think.